# Mailjet e-mail is empty when attaching a file to it

Tags: node.js, loopback, mailjet

I have this bit of code that creates a calendar for a specific delivery, and then attaches it to an e-mail to be send. The problem is, when I attach the .ics file, the template breaks (no text, no pictures... nothing). Only the calendar file gets send (even though it does get send to the right e-mail).

```
  const event = await this.calendarService.getEventForDelivery(deliveryId);

  await this.sendMailjetTemplate('4069368', d.email, [{contentType: 'text/calendar', content: event}], {
    ASN: d.identifier,
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by specifying a "text" attribute to my mail.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).